# Directive acting like bottomsheet of angular material

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I'd like to create a form that appears on the screen as the UI components "Bottom Sheet" of Angular Material.

When the user clicks on a button, a panel (div ???) appears in the bottom of the page with the form. This panel overlays the current page and if the user clicks (or swipe down the panel) the panel disappears.

I've made an implementation of this form in a classic "Bottom Sheet" but this UI Component is designed only to display buttons (and not inputs) and there is limitations when I try to give focus to an input.

Is there an existing directive that do the job or someone has some advise to write it from scratch because I don't see where to start.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you found some answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I've just start learning Material and AngularJS some weeks ago, so I don't think to be able to answer correctly to your question, what I would do will follow.

*** You must be able to read code then...**

[Here is a quick demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqgBdo) that I made on Codepen.

I put the following form in it and it seems to display and 'works' (no focus yet)

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container>
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea ng-model="user.description"></textarea>
</md-input-container>
```

Don't hesitate to fork it to show us what is the issue you dealing with.
Maybe it will be easier and faster to start from there.

Since Material AngularJS is an open source project, the source code is available for you to consult.
So if you manage to create a directive from scratch, I would suggest to start by understanding how the 'bottomSheet' & 'sidenav' components are built, to combine them and get the best of both. As the 'sidenav' directive can contains forms.

[Here is the link](https://github.com/angular/material/tree/master/src/components) to the 'components' folder of the project on Github.

*** Its version is 0.10.1**

If you find it too laborious, there is always the vanilla javascript way of doing it with simple HTML, some CSS...

Hope this could help you figure it out while you wait for a good answer.